# UserAgent xamarin android not setting

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, user-agent

I'm trying to put User Agent Strings to webview in xamarin android
and it's work but in somehow User-Angent not setting
i try to delete cookies and still not setting

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TwitterForm);


            _webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);      
            txt55 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt55);
         _webview.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; yie11; rv:11.0) like Gecko";

            _webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            _webview.LoadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/login");
            _webview.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            _webview.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

         }
```

Comment: you can try the code `var ua = _webview.Settings.UserAgentString

            _webview.Settings.UserAgentString = ua+ ";Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; yie11; rv:11.0) like Gecko";`

Comment: not working :((